# Is there a way to memorize properties that refer to the project and not to the scene?

Tags: python, properties, scene

I have properties pi like bpy.props.PointerProperty, this is very useful to me, I often use them to refer to the scene in use, but I'm having to create new scenes and all references to other scenes when I add a new scene return to the default value (rightly) I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having to create a function that copies these values (since they are many) The current example is the one I have, that is properties that refer to bpy.context.scene:

```
class MySceneProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(default=false)
    my_int: IntProperty(default=0)
    my_float: FloatProperty(default=0.0)

def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.scene_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySceneProperty)
```

This is usually very convenient, but currently I am dealing with the creation of new scenes and it creates the problem that these values return to the default state, there is something above bpy.types.Scene?

Edit: 
I was trying to copy the properties from one scene to another but I realize I can't, this should happen when bpy.data.scenes.new is created